# __rsub__ and __rtruediv__ with fractions

Tags: python, math, fractions, magic-methods

I'm attempting to use the `__rsub__` function in a class I've made called Fraction.

Here's the Fraction class code:

```
def __init__(self, num, denom):
    ''' Creates a new Fraction object num/denom'''
    self.num = num
    self.denom = denom
    self.reduce()

def __repr__(self):
    ''' returns string representation of our fraction'''
    return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.denom)

def reduce(self):
    ''' converts our fractional representation into reduced form'''
    divisor = gcd(self.num, self.denom)
    self.num = self.num // divisor
    self.denom = self.denom // divisor
def __sub__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other,Fraction) == True:
        newnum = self.num * other.denom - self.denom*other.num
        newdenom = self.denom * other.denom
        return Fraction(newnum, newdenom)
```

Now if I do `__radd__` or `__rmul__` by using: `return self + other` or `return self * other` respectively, it will perform the desired result.  However, doing `__rsub__` and `__rtruediv__` do not work by simply changing the operator.  How can I fix this?

Essentially, the code calling the functions is:

```
f = Fraction(2,3)
g = Fraction(4,8)
print("2 - f: ", 2 - f)
print("2 / f: ", 2 / f)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please don't ever write `== True`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to convert `other` to a `Fraction` to make this work:

```
def __rsub__(self, other):
    return Fraction(other, 1) - self
```

Since `__rsub__()` only gets called if `other` is *not* of type `Fraction`, we don't need any type checking -- we simply assume it is an integer.

Your current implementation of `__sub__()` also needs some work -- it returns nothing if `other` does not have the type `Fraction`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you type-check, and return `None` when the second operand is not `Fraction` (also, `if isinstance(...):`, not `if isinstance(...) == True:`). You need to coerce the argument instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the isinstance. I've made the adjustment :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to implement an "r" operation is 1) check to make sure *other* is a type you know how to handle 2) if not, return NotImplemented, and 3) if so, convert is to a type than can interact with self:

```
def __radd__(self, other):
    if not instance(other, (int, Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    converted = Fraction(other)
    return converted + self
```